# Pandas convert column values to columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is 24 columns wide and 185,912 rows and would like to transform the dataframe such that the values in one column (name) become new columns with the values from another column (s_counter).

```
    uuid    start_time  s_counter   name
0   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 8:35:15  16.0  statistics$$total
1   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 8:35:15  12.0  statistics$$passed
2   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 8:35:15  4.0   statistics$$skipped
3   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 8:35:15  4.0   statistics$$to_investigate$total
4   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 8:35:15  4.0   statistics$$to_investigate$ti001
```

Should become

```
  uuid start_time statistics$$total statistics$$passed statistics$$skipped statistics$$to_investigate$ti001
0 5f7c88804c4b170001683c13 16.0 12.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
```

Also acceptable would be if we retained the 4 rows and the newly created columns contained NULL where there was no value.

Note in the larger dataframe some of these columns may not be present, i.e. if there are no values for statistics$$skipped then this entry would not be available for that particiular uuid, in these cases we would still need/want the column it would simply have a NULL  or 0 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this appears to be working.

```
d = {"uuid": ["5f7c88804c4b170001683c13"] * 5, 
     "start_time": [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 6, 8, 35, 15)] * 5, 
     "s_counter": [16., 12., 4., 4., 4.],
     "name": ["statistics$$total", "statistics$$passed", "statistics$$skipped", "statistics$$to_investigate$total", "statistics$$to_investigate$ti001"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df2 = df.pivot(df.columns[:-2], columns='name', values='s_counter')
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I suggest we just loop over row with simple logical decision, following code will working correctly even when rows with same `uuid` are not adjacent in original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {"uuid": ["5f7c88804c4b170001683c13"] * 5, 
     "start_time": [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 6, 8, 35, 15)] * 5, 
     "s_counter": [16., 12., 4., 4., 4.],
     "name": ["statistics$$total", "statistics$$passed", "statistics$$skipped", "statistics$$to_investigate$total", "statistics$$to_investigate$ti001"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
column_name = ["uuid", "start_time"] + list(df["name"].unique())
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_name)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["uuid"] in new_df["uuid"].values:
        new_df.at[new_df.index[new_df["uuid"] == row["uuid"]], row["name"]] = row["s_counter"]
    else:
        new_row = {"uuid": row["uuid"], "start_time": row["start_time"], row["name"]: row["s_counter"]}
        new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

new_df
```

Outputs on Colab:

```
    uuid    start_time  statistics$$total   statistics$$passed  statistics$$skipped     statistics$$to_investigate$total  statistics$$to_investigate$ti001
0   5f7c88804c4b170001683c13    2020-10-06 08:35:15     16.0    12.0    4.0     4.0     4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index and then `unstack()` for this. You can chain the commands to make it more compact:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['uuid','start_time','name'])
df2 = df2.unstack('name')
```

You can rename the columns to eliminate the resulting multilevel index:

```
df2.columns = [c[1] for c in df2.columns]
```

Then bring the index levels back as columns:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

I'll note that you also didn't have `start_time` in the output example, and it will be faster if you drop that column from the df first and don't index it. You could always merge it back in at the end on the `uuid` field.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, the exclusion of `start_time` was an oversight on my part it should be included in the final dataframe.